# Ubuntu 18.04 failed to move file from windows directory to Ubuntu

Tags: 18.04, filesystem

I have dual boot os installed windows-10 and Ubuntu-18.04. Now logged in Ubuntu-18.04, I want to move files from windows directory to Ubuntu directory. Though I have the permission to read the files from windows-10 directory I failed to move it. It shows the following error....

```
$ mv Win10_1803_English_x64.iso  /media/saif/707C3EF27C3EB328/
mv: inter-device move failed: 'Win10_1803_English_x64.iso' to '/media/saif/707C3EF27C3EB328/Win10_1803_English_x64.iso'; unable to remove target: Read-only file system
```

[image: see the screenshots]

Answer (score 0):

Have you disabled fastboot on the Windows installation? Windows doesn't unmount disks on shutdown with fastboot enabled as it (as the name implies) speeds up boot times, which causes access issues for Linux machines utilizing those same disks. To force it to shutdown fully, follow this guide:

https://www.isumsoft.com/windows-10/2-ways-to-perform-a-full-shutdown.html